# Live streaming google tango's data

Tags: google-project-tango

I am working with Google Tango to extract data from the tablet and use it at the same time in another device. I am trying to record the data and use it with another laptop via live streaming.

I've looked at various topics about it and I found the Paraview topic. However the App records the data, save as ZIP file and send it via bluetooth(which is fine for me). I do not want to save the file as ZIP format and send it to another device. I want to record and use the data via live streaming(bluetooth or Wi-Fi).

Is that possible? How can I do it? 
Paraview shared the source code so I think I can change it make it work for me. However I am not really used to programming.

Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use sockets: setting a socket server on your computer and connecting to it via your tablet. It is a way to transfer information via what is called, for example, a TCP protocol.

However, there *might* be a more efficient way to do what you want to achieve with USB debugging. I did not got able to make USB debugging work yet on the tablet and computer I worked with.

Answer (score 0):

You could use TangoAnywhere, I developed it so you can broadcast Google Tango position and orientation data to any device.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.grauonline.tangoanywhere

You connect using a TCP client on your PC/Mac (simple TCP client written Python or something) to port 8080 of your Tango device and will get the position data in realtime.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [Tango ROS Streamer app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.intermodalics.tango_ros_streamer) which enables you to choose which data (position, point cloud, RGB image) to stream or not.

You will need ROS to retrieve the data. On Linux ROS is easy to install, otherwise use a docker image of ROS.

Caution: the theorical WiFi bandwidth does not enable to stream all the RGB frames at full resolution without dropping some.